# What's the professional term for this type of API?

Tags: api, http, https

A URL in which you add the parameters in the end of it, and it gives to back results for the specific parameters given, for example:

api.website.com/something.json?foo=2&bar=1

Comment: `/something` is an endpoint which accepts querystring parameters. Not sure if I've ever seen and endpoint URL with `.json` in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way looks like the way you mentioned as

```
domain/cgi_path?param_0=val_0&...&param_n=val_n
```

but it could be in any other scheme too like

```
domain/cgi_path/sub_path_as_param <<-- note the subpath as param instead of param
domain/images/2 <<-- instead of domain/images?page=2
```

or

```
domain?pg=cgi_path?args=blah_blah <<-- note the path as arg for one global path
```

About the `.json` part, it's not very common, but it's a human goody thing informs the dev about the possible response type(if it's a troll)
but the type could be set as a arg too like

```
domain/cgi_path?arg0=val0&response_type=xml
domain/cgi_path/xml?arg0=val0
```

Finally go with any way you like and looks easy for you. But remember to make a great documentation for it.